# How to overlay two 1d arrays in NumPy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have one numpy array like this:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

and a second, shorter one:

```
arr2 = [-1, -2, -3]
```

I'd like to overlay this shorter one on the larger array so that I end up like this:

```
result = [-1, -2, -3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I thought of perhaps slicing the original array and concatenating with the second, but that seems so inefficient.

Is there a NumPy way of just assigning all positions of the shorter array into the second?

Comment: Does `arr[:3] = arr2` work?

Comment: Or use `numpy.add.at` - https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use slicing to replace first `len(smaller_array)` elements in `larger_array` with `smaller_array` as follows:

```
arr[:len(arr2)] = arr2
```